# How to use custom OpenSSL installation directory on Tomcat 8 especially when using Tomcat Native Library on Linux

Tags: tomcat, openssl

I've search about this topic a lot and doesn't seem to find any clue about it. The case is that I don't have root access on CentOS ATM and I need to run Tomcat with Tomcat Native Library 1.2.7 with SSL. I've successfully run Tomcat with Tomcat Native Library but with SSLEngine off. Is there any way to point the SSL engine to custom directory in Tomcat? The apr work with custom directory (I put it in user home) using custom path in Tomcat docs but I can't found any custom path options for OpenSSL.

Thank you for every help

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: You ought to be able to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in Tomcat's `bin/setenv.sh` file. That will change the linker's library load-ordering to include your custom OpenSSL version instead of the system's default. It should work with APR, too, but it's probably more clear to use whatever mechanism you are already using to specify the APR path. (By the way, how are you doing that?)

Comment: I'm using this in setenv.sh : CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/apr/lib -Xms64m -Xmx2g -Xss228k -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1500 -XX:GCTimeRatio=9 -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC".
Actually I after I read your comment, it seems that the installation seems to work with apr at that time (when I still have root access) and I can point to usual local lib folder. As far as compilation of Tomcat Native, I can do with the OpenSSL pointing to my home folder (OpenSSL-1.0.2g folder), but it doesn't work when the Tomcat is running, it says some cryptho.so missing